# How do I write an update join postgres query as queryset in Django 1.9?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

## Situation

I have the following query in Postgres 9.5.

```
update warehouse_shelf
  set package_count = counter.result
from (
    select count(id) as result, shelf_id 
    from warehouse_package 
    group by shelf_id
) counter
where counter.shelf_id = warehouse_shelf.id;
```

These are my tables.

```
warehouse_shelf
+----+------+---------------+
| ID | NAME | PACKAGE_COUNT |
+----+------+---------------+
|  1 | S1   |             3 |
|  2 | S2   |             1 |
|  3 | S3   |             0 |
+----+------+---------------+

warehouse_package
+----+------+---------------+
| ID | NAME | SHELF_ID      |
+----+------+---------------+
|  1 | P1   |             1 |
|  2 | P2   |             1 |
|  3 | P3   |             1 |
|  4 | P4   |             2 |
+----+------+---------------+
```

## Question

How do I execute the query above whenever I make a change to an individual package (e.g. save, delete, create, update etc) via django model?

I want to execute using django queryset if possible and avoid executing it as raw query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have models and their foreign key relations:

```
 from django.db.models import Count

 shelves = WhShelf.objects.all()     

 for shelf in shelves:
      count = WhPackage.objects.filter(shelf_id=shelf.id).aggregate(Count('shelf'))
      shelf.update(package_count=count[shelf__count'])
```

Alterantively, you can run a single query:

```
WhShelf.objects.annotate(package_count=WhPackage.objects.
                filter(shelf_id=shelf.id).aggregate(Count('shelf'))['shelf__count'])
```

Comment: Also look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/ for aggregates

Comment: Your method will run multiple queries due to a loop for the shelves. Is there a way to update all the shelves package_count in a single django query?

Comment: WhPackage.objects.filter(shelf_id=shelf.id).aggregate(Count('shelf')) will return you a dictionary which you can check for shelf__count value within the nested query and set to package_count.  See more at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/